# c# using properties in struct scope, when used for winapi?

Tags: c#, winapi, optimization, struct

I kindly wanted to ask if it is recommendable to add properties for fields in a struct scope, if the struct is used for an winAPI call (f.ex. dllimport("xxx.dll")).

The question poped up when I let run the code Analysis - saying me, that I should use property accessors instead having public fields in struct.

And true, onthinking I would recommend that too, but - is an API call still possible with the 'so code optimized' struct?

May be I ought to show what I mean:

as everybody knows it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct someAPICallStructure
{
    public int cbSize;
    public IntPtr hwndParent;
    public string pszMessageText;
    public string pszCaptionText;
    public IntPtr hbmBanner;
}
```

as the code analyzer wishes:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct someAPICallStructure
{
    public CBSize
    {
        get
        {
            return cbSize;
        }
        set
        {
            cbSize = value;
        }
    }
    .... and properties for all other fields too ...

    int cbSize;
    IntPtr hwndParent;
    string pszMessageText;
    string pszCaptionText;
    IntPtr hbmBanner;
}
```

Or could I even use like this?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct someAPICallStructure
{
    public CBSize {get; set;}
    ... and with all other fields too ...
}
```

And even further; can I add equals(..) and other suggested methods to the struct and it works still for the API Call?

Comment: The compiler like to have all variables initialized so that is why you are getting the warning.  So using following should get rid or warnings : public int cbSize { get; set;}

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28488057/1997232)? I'd disable the warning.

Comment: Yeah, disable the warning for interop types like this

Comment: @jdweng How does converting a field into a property change whether or not the struct is initialized?

Comment: You cannot read.  It is a warning.  Using {get;set;} removes the compiler warning that variables are not initialized.

Comment: @jdweng That's a strangely aggressive response. And one that doesn't seem to match reality. Consider this program:  `struct foo
    {
        public int i { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foo f;
            Console.WriteLine(f.i);
        }
    }`

The compiler rejects this with a compiler error: `CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'f'`  So, I'm still confused. I'm still wondering why you are talking about initialization given that no mention of that can be found in the question.